# Using an SD card for backup?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, sd-card

I want to backup some files that I regularly work on on a separate medium. It is however not very convenient if I have to plug in usb drives or external harddisks all the time as I have to carry my laptop around a lot. Now I had the idea to use an SD card that I can just leave it plugged in my laptop. (The idea of this backup is just having the files saved on another medium than the harddrive.) Now I have following questions:

- Are SD cards suitable for this task?
- Does it damage the SD cards if they are repeatedly accessed for writing?
- How long can the data be stored on an SD card when it is not plugged in?

(All those points compared to an USB drive or an external harddrive.)

Comment: I would say this question is slightly opinion based. I’m my opinion an SD card is what I would least rely on for data backup. SD cards seem to regularly corrupt, especially with cameras, game trail cams, etc. An example of this not working for a PC is a friend of mine. He had 109 GB of stuff on an SD card on his computer he always kept plugged in. It suddenly went corrupt and everything is gone. I have much more trust in an external HDD. Depending on how much data you have to back up, and the file types I would highly recommend a cloud based solution over other media.

Comment: @DrZoo: in theory the reliability of SD cards can be measured and statistics collected can tell us how much reliability to expect.  The fact that you replied with your opinions, based on personal experiences, does not make the _question_ opinion-based.  It makes _your response_ opinion-based.  I'm not saying your opinion is wrong, as it's possible that careful measurements and statistics would arrive at a similar conclusion.  But your statement that _the question_ is opinion-based is misguided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do what you are describing, but an external drive or SSD is better suited because:

faster performance (SSD)
Lifespan - see below

btw the data can be stored on the SSD "forever" - unlike CDs

Common criticism of flash-based storage like SDHC cards is the lack of "wear leveling." Wear leveling is a technique used in SSDs for prolonging the lifespan of flash memory. Flash memory is limited by the number of times data can be written and erased to the medium. Wear-leveling works around this limitation by arranging data so that erasures and re-writes are distributed evenly across the medium. In this way, no single sector of the flash prematurely fails due to a high number of write cycles.

But some dispute the limitation because:
For example, the 16GB A-DATA SDHC card has an estimated endurance or lifetime of 1,000,000 write cycles. What does that mean is "real world" terms? You would have to constantly write, erase and re-write data non-stop for several years before you need to be concerned about failure.

Comment: @flawr, let me add a couple of considerations to the good advice here (+1). 1) There's a lot of quality variation in flash memory cards.  Theoretically, they should last a very long time, but there is a lot of low-grade crap in the marketplace that fails in a short time.  If you use an SD card, get a reputable brand and regularly back it up to something else.  2) Carry it with you but insert it only when you're actively using it.  If it is mounted, malware can infect it or trash it.  (cont'd)

Comment: Whatever degree of risk there is, it is expanded if it is accessible to the malware by being attached when it doesn't need to be.  The same thing applies to an external HDD you might leave plugged into your home system for backup.  If malware corrupts everything attached, you no longer have a backup to recover with.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks, you mention some good points, up to now I only thought about the protection against hardware failure, and not about protection against malware.

Answer (score 4):

- SD cards are meant to be written to.  There is no reason not to use one.
- Yes, flash medium will *eventually* wear out over time.  However, modern flash media will last a *very, very* long time.
- SD cards are non-volatile, therefore the data will survive, even without being plugged in for many years, if not decades.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have researched online about this, it really is a difficult issue to resolve. Hard disks do not wear out in terms of writes, but physical parts means almost always means they will fail faster. SD cards are more reliable in terms of survivability in rough handling, as dropping a hard drive is going to be a very rough day. Limited writes on SD cards and no wear leveling as @TomEus mentioned can be bad. Speeds can be better than HDDs if a high end SDHC storage technology is chosen. SD cards are very portable, HDD very clunky and need to be set on a table.

TLDR for me: If you buy a good SD card, and you know the write cycles are good, great, stick with that. If you know that the writes are no good, HDD for sure. Also, if the amount of data is a lot (over 1TB) use a hard drive at that point, SD card is far from value for money.